# TouchXML deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, xml, touchxml

I tried to download it and google says it's deprecated. Deprecated by what? What are the new replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not deprecated. Check out the most recent version from its [GitHub page](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML). It is just basically in "support mode", according to Schwa's recent message in the development group:

> TouchXML is basically in "support mode" now. There's no new interesting development going on with it, and the only changes you should expect to see going forward are bug fixes and small functional additions. You can treat the master branch as stable. Any large changes have previously been and will be made on the Develop branch and then merged into the stable master branch after testing.

[(source)](http://groups.google.com/group/touchcode-dev/browse_thread/thread/55eb14e4fd636ed2)